# Assignment via `:=` in a for loop (R data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to assign some new variables within a `for` loop (I'm trying to create some variables with common structure, but which are subsample-dependent).

I've tried for the life of me to re-produce this error on sample data and I can't. Here's code that works & gets the gist of what I want to do:

```r
DT <- data.table(
  id = rep(1:100, each = 20L),
  period = rep(-9:10, 100L),
  grp = rep(sample(4L, size = 100L, replace = TRUE), each = 20L),
  y = runif(2000, min=0, max=5), key = c("id", "period")
)
DT[ , x := cumsum(y), by = id]
DT2 <- DT[id %in% seq(1, 100, by=2)]
DT3 <- DT[id %in% seq(1, 100, by=3)]

for (dd in list(DT, DT2, DT3)){
  setkey(setkey(dd, grp)[dd[period==0, sum(x), by = grp], x_at_0_by_grp := V1], id, period)
}
```

This works fine--however, when I do this to my own code, it generates the Invalid `.internal.selfref` warning (and doesn't create the variable I want):

> In `[.data.table`(setkey(dt, treatment), dt[posting_rel == 0,
>   sum(current_balance),  :   Invalid .internal.selfref detected and
>   fixed by taking a copy of the
>   whole table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an
>   earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or been created
>   manually using structure() or similar). Avoid key<-, names<- and
>   attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table.
>   Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and
>   ?setattr. Also, in R<=v3.0.2, list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 and
>   DT2 (R's list() used to copy named objects); please upgrade to
>   R>v3.0.2 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please
>   report to datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.

In fact, when I subset my data to *only* those columns needed within the merge, it also works fine on my data (though doesn't save to the original data sets).

This suggests to me it's a problem with keying, but I'm explicitly setting the keys every step of the way. I'm completely lost on how to debug this from here because I can't get the error to repeat except on my full data set.

If I break out the operation into steps, the error arises at the merge step:

```
for (dd in list(DT, DT2, DT3)){
  dummy <- dd[period==0, sum(x), by = grp]
  setkey(dd, grp)
  dd[dummy, x_at_0_by_grp := V1] #***ERROR HERE***
  setkey(dd, id, period)
}
```

---

Quick update--also produces the error if I cast this with `lapply` instead of within a `for` loop.

Any ideas what on earth is going on here?

---

UPDATE: I've come up with a workaround by doing:

```
nnames <- c("dt", "dt2", "dt3")

dt_list <- list(DT, DT2, DT3)

for (ii in 1:3){
  dummy <- copy(dt_list[[ii]])
  dummy[ , x_at_0_by_grp := sum(x[period == 0]), by=grp]
  assign(nnames[ii], dummy)
}
```

Would still like to understand what's going on, and perhaps a better way of assigning variables iteratively in situations like this.

Comment: I don't have an explanation for your bug, but you might consider pooling this data into a single data.table and working with that. `DT <- rbindlist(list(dt[,src:=1],dt2[,src:=2],dt3[,src:=3]))` Even if you don't want to stack the data, your second step does not require a merge, just use `sum(x[period==0])` ... `DT[,x_at_0_by_grp:=sum(x[period==0]),by="src,grp"]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip for avoiding a merge, I hadn't thought of that. However, the error still occurs--suggesting to me the problem is the combination of looping over a `list` call of a `data.table` (which is mentioned as troublesome in other questions involving `Invalid .internal.selfref`) and using the `:=` operator, rather than the merge itself.

Comment: Also, I'd prefer not to pool the data because 1) each subset has ~300,000 observations and 2) i could define your `src` within my main data set as an indicator for subsample containment, but the number of subsample-specific variables means I'd have to keep 20-30 variables with subsample-specific names in the original dataset--feels more natural to loop over data sets with a consistent name for the variables.

Comment: Hm, weird that `copy` did the trick; I think you could post that as an answer. Yeah, I can see why you wouldn't want to stack the data sets like that. Anyway, I've posted my next suggestion as an answer, since it is so long.

Comment: Same doing this, but this ex do not warn
``
iris <- data.table(iris)
cols <- c("Petal.Width", ~Petal.Length/Petal.Width, ~Sepal.Width-Petal.Width)
names <- c("Petal.Width", "Width.Length.Relation", "Width.Length.Difference")
if(any(unlist(lapply(cols, inherits, what = "formula")))){
  for(col in 1:length(cols)){
    if(inherits(cols[[col]], "formula")){
      text_f <- tail(as.character(cols[[col]]), 1)
      name_f <- names[[col]]
      # se produce un warning
      text_f <- enquote(text_f)
      iris[,
         (name_f) := eval(parse(text = text_f))
      ]
    }
  }
}
``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 20-30 criteria, keeping them outside of a list (with manual names like `dt2`, etc.) is too clunky, so I'll just assume you have them all in `dt_list`.

I suggest making tables with just the stat you're computing, and then `rbind`ing them:

```
xxt <- rbindlist(lapply(1:length(dt_list),function(i) 
         dt_list[[i]][,list(cond=i,xx=sum(x[period==0])),by=grp]))
```

which creates

```
    grp cond       xx
 1:   1    1 623.3448
 2:   2    1 784.8438
 3:   4    1 699.2362
 4:   3    1 367.7196
 5:   1    2 323.6268
 6:   4    2 307.0374
 7:   2    2 447.0753
 8:   3    2 185.7377
 9:   1    3 275.4897
10:   4    3 243.0214
11:   2    3 149.6041
12:   3    3 166.3626
```

You can easily merge back if you really want those vars. For example, for `dt2`:

```
myi = 2
setkey(dt_list[[myi]],grp)[xxt[cond==myi,list(grp,xx)]]
```

This doesn't resolve the bug you're running into, but I think is a better approach.

Comment: I like this. Two concerns: 1) some conditions aren't done by any subgroup--for example, one variable is quartiles of `x` (done using `cut`), so storing this separately requires as many rows as the original table; 2) If I want merge back all the contents of `xxt` (which I will-I'm eventually running regressions with these variables as controls, so it's much cleaner to have all variables in the same `data.table` and set `,data=dt`), it seems I'll need a for loop again, which suggests to me I'll run into the same problem (haven't tested), unless it really is a problem with `:=` only.

Comment: My hunch is it's a bug in the `:=`. It sounds like you have a pretty complicated procedure in mind; I don't know how to address either of those concerns.