# Multiple execution of a script either with an apply function or with a for loop

Tags: r, loops, apply

I would like to run [this](https://datascienceplus.com/identify-describe-plot-and-removing-the-outliers-from-the-dataset/) script multiple times(and do a few other things after that). The data is in a text file (named `test.txt`) in the following form:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   2   1   9
3   5   1   3   0
2   NA  4   13  2
```

and is imported using

```
test <- read.table("test.txt",header=TRUE)
```

The data can be converted to a different format and it can be used without headers.

I know I should use an `apply` function, and I Googled a lot about using both `apply` functions and for loops, but I wasn't able to implement them successfully.

For example, I get an error message after running the following code:

```
for(i in names(table)){
  message("Name of the data set:", i)
  outlierKD(table, i)}
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i' not found`.

I found a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639093/why-does-r-store-the-loop-variable-index-dummy-in-memory) about the loop's index and also discovered that `exists(i)` returns false while the message appears properly.

I would like to execute the `outlier` function that checks for outliers in all columns of the data either using `apply` functions or loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I wanted to modify the script a bit, and store it in an .r file as well the script that will execute it multiple times(and does some other things), like this:)

```
test <- read.table("test.txt",header=TRUE)
source("outlierKD_mod.r")
source("loopscript.r")
loopscript(test)
```

This didn't work, and I started creating a single script (where no functions are declared) based on @Samuel's code which can be copy-pasted into the R console. The only thing that had to be modified on the outlierKD script is that this line had to be replaced:

```
assign(as.character(as.list(match.call())$test), test, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

with this:

```
test[x]=var_name
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605405/7577014) command will remove the column added to the data frame by the outlier check:

```
test <- subset(test, select = -c(i) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
source("https://datascienceplus.com/rscript/outlier.R")

A = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 3)
B = c(2, 5, 0, 1, 6)
C = c(2, 1, 4, 7, 8)
D = c(1, 3, 99, 4, 2)
E = c(9, 0, 2, 8, 4)

df = data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)

x <- 0

for (i in df) {
  x <- x + 1
  names <- names(df)
  message("Variable: ", names[x])
  outlierKD(dt = df, var = i)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: For some reason when the script has to remove the outlier, the original column remains unchanged and a new column named `i` is created, where the outlier is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use of for-loop is easier in this case.

```
test <- read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE) #copied and pasted
test

source("https://datascienceplus.com/rscript/outlier.R") #function

for(i in 1:ncol(test)) outlierKD(dt=test, i)
```

Then in the R console (interactively), press key `Y` to reveal plots

Comment: Unfortunately, the script doesn't "see" the data this way:
`List of outliers: 0 from 1 observations
Proportion (%) of outliers: 0
Mean of the outliers: NaN
Mean without removing outliers: 1
Mean if we remove outliers: 1`