# How to define 'local' variables in R?

Tags: r, variables, scope, local

For example, inside a for loop, I want to define some variables to do some operation, but I want them to be automatically removed once the iteration is over.

However, if I assing a value to a variable using `<-`, even after the execution of the loop ends, the variable still persists and I have to remove it, manually, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Anything inside a function is local so best to use functions instead of loops or maybe use `local`?

Comment: @NelsonGon as far as I know, R does not have any syntax like `local`, like python has (I have just tried using that prefix while defining a variable in a for loop, it didn't wokr)

Comment: I rarely write explicit loops in R, could you add some example? See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639093/why-does-r-store-the-loop-variable-index-dummy-in-memory) alternatives.

Comment: This uses `local` but then everything is `local`: `number <- 1:5;
res <- numeric(5);
local(for(i in number){
 print(res[i] + 2) 
})`

Comment: @NelsonGon oh, I didn't know that one could from a for loop like in the accepted answer.

Comment: @NelsonGon You gave me 3 different ways of doing exactly what I was asking; thanks a lot. I suggest you turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers illustrates the use of `local` within a loop in R:

```
number <- 1:5
res <- numeric(5)
local(for(i in number){
  res2 <-res[i] + 42
  print(res2)
})

[1] 42
[1] 42
[1] 42
[1] 42
[1] 42
```

The above does not create `res2` in `.GlobalEnv` unlike the following:

```
 for(i in number){
  res2 <-res[i] + 42
  print(res2)
 }
```

Alternatively, you could avoid loops and use `*apply` and/or use functions that use local variables by design. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639093/why-does-r-store-the-loop-variable-index-dummy-in-memory)